# SwiftUI: ForEach iterating over an array of key-value pairs

Tags: swift, dictionary, swiftui

I have a sorted dictionary as so:

`let ingredients = extractIngredients().sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key} )`

`extractIngredients()` returns a `[String : String]`, and `ingredients` should be a `[(String, String)]`. However, I want to display the key-value pairs with `ForEach`, but I'm not sure how I would go about that. This is my loop:

```
ForEach(ingredients) { pair in
    Text("**\(pair.key)**: \(pair.value)")
}
```

It gives me the following error:

`Cannot convert value of type '[Dictionary<String, String>.Element]' (aka 'Array<(key: String, value: String)>') to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'`

Not sure how to combat this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tuple doesn't conform to Hashable so you need to explain what the unique identifier is by using the `id:` argument. We can safely use the first item of the tuple since that is a dictionary key

```
ForEach(ingredients, id: \.0) { pair in
    Text("**\(pair.0)**: \(pair.1)")
}
```